# Get attr('id') from a <td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, and the checkb starts from checkb01 to chekb342.

```
<tr>
     <td class="specs_under">Specs</td>
     <td id="checkb77" class='checkb'><input type="checkbox" id="add_remove77" class="change_image77"/></td>
     <td  class="specs_under_value" id="specs_unit77">1</td>
     <td rowspan="13" class="specs_under_value" id="specs_itempr77">15</td>
     <td class="specs_under_value" id="specs_quantity77">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="specs_under_value" id="specs_packageprice77">0.125</td>
</tr>
```

I tried using  this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkb").toggle(function() {
        var cid = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('id');

    },function() {
        alert('checkbox unchekced');

    }
```

How do I get the value of the id in `<td>` respective checkbox clicks using jquery

Thanks
Jean

**Guys I need to get the value of  id  when the checkbox is clicked, not the checkbox id**

Comment: Why are you going for the TD id and not the checkboxes themselves?

Comment: Because I have to get the values from further td's either way it does not give me the values(attr('id')).

Answer (score 9):

```
$(':checkbox').toggle(function() {
    var cid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(cid);
}, function() {
    alert('checkbox unchekced');
}​);​
```

Comment: I could do that.  I have to copy/paste that 342 times for each <td>

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.

Comment: @darin, How can I get the attrib of a <td>

Comment: Use .parent() to get the checkbox's parent element.

Comment: `$(this).parent('td').attr('id')`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the id of the enclosing td (not the checkbox itself) consider using the .closest() function.

ex:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    alert(id + ' : ' + this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the values by either attaching the event handlers directly onto the checkbox (`toggle()` automatically cancels the default checking action, so we're using `change()` here):

```
$('.checkb :checkbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        // Do somethin'
        alert(this.id);
    } else {
        // Do something else
        alert('Unchecked!');
    }
});
```

If you really want to use `toggle`, this code works, somewhat:

```
$(".checkb").toggle(function() {
    var cid = $(this).children(':checkbox').attr('id');
    alert(cid);
}, function() {
    alert('checkbox unchekced');
});
```

However, because of the above mentioned default action cancellation, the checkbox can never be checked.

Comment: I could get the checkbox checked thats fine, but its the attr('id') I cannot get

Comment: @Jean http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/CeFPh/ You can see the behavior I'm talking about. Otherwise, I'm not entirely sure what you want here

Comment: @yi span is okay, but I want to do it in a table.

Comment: @Jean Which makes no difference - you are using the class selector here, not tag, so the tag you're using should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of right now is adding a *rel* attribute to the input tag and an id to the tr tag like:

```
<tr id="row77">
     <td class="specs_under">Specs</td>
     <td id="checkb77" class='checkb'><input type="checkbox" id="add_remove77" class="change_image77" rel="row77"/></td>
     <td  class="specs_under_value" id="specs_unit77">1</td>
     <td rowspan="13" class="specs_under_value" id="specs_itempr77">15</td>
     <td class="specs_under_value" id="specs_quantity77">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="specs_under_value" id="specs_packageprice77">0.125</td>
</tr>
```

and then use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('checkbox:checked').each(function() {
         var id = $(this).attr('rel').substr(3,$(this).attr('rel').length); // 77
         var specs_packageprice = $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')+' #specs_packageprice'+id).html(); //0.125
         // More code...
     }
</script>
```

I also think you can simplify this alot...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery 1.4.2 (the newest version, I think), I'd consider using delegate(). Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("table").delegate(":checkbox", "click", function() {alert($(this).attr("id");})
})
```

Obviously, you can do whatever you want in your click handler.

What delegate does is attach to the table containing all your checkboxes. Anytime an input element in the table is clicked, the handler will fire. If you have other inputs in the table, you'll need to check to be sure you have an element you want. You could check if type is checkbox. I'd recommend giving your table an id, and replacing "table" with the id in the above.

Alternatively, you can attach a click handler to every input in the table, but that's probably not going to be easier, and will likely be slower.

Finally, if you're not using 1.4.2, but are using at least 1.3, you can use live() instead of delegate.